# Merging multiple master branches into each other on git/GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repo that started its life out with only a `master` branch, and I pushed a bunch of code to it. Then I created a `development` branch (via `git checkout -b development`) locally on my machine and pushed it (via `git push origin development`), but no changes were made to it, other than just creating it (meaning `master` and `development` were now identical).

Another developer was *supposed* to create a `fizzbuzz` feature branch off of the `development` branch, but instead created it off of `master` (which was up to date). She now has pushed her `fizzbuzz` branch to GitHub.

Ultimately I want `fizzbuzz` merged into `development`, which would then kick off a CI build and DEV deployment. Then, at a later time, I will merge `development` into `master`.

But I don't think this is possible to do because she created `fizzbuzz` off of `master` instead of `development`. Is it? And if not, what's the solution? Is there a way for her to "rebase" `fizzbuzz` to be a branch of `development` (if so what are the commands?), or some other alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very nearly answered your own question! `git rebase development fizzbuzz` will rebase `fizzbuzz` onto `development`. If you then `git push origin fizzbuzz --force`, GitHub will update the base branch.

Comment: Thanks @kfb (+1) - I figured it would involve a `rebase` but I've never needed to use that before! Quick followup question if you don't mind, just to confirm I understand: when you say "*...will rebase `fizzbuzz` onto `development`*", do you mean that it will be as if she branched `development` in the first place? And will this only work if the branches are identical/clean? Meaning what happens if `development` has new code that was not on there when she (accidentally) branched `master`? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it will be as if `fizzbuzz` always branched from `development`. As for your second question, the answer is "it depends". [This link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) should shed some light on rebasing in general, and [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/) talks about what happens if there are conflicts.